# Rails: manually clear asset pipeline cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I know that rails clears the asset pipeline cache by itself when files are modified, but I have a special scenario.  I am feeding my application as an HTML response to an ajax request, cross domain using [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to bypass CORS.

The problem is that every time the ajax request goes through on the person's browser, I get a new application.js file:

*this is three requests..three separate application.js files*
[image: error]

If I could clear the asset pipeline cache before the request is initiated, I think I could avoid this issue.  Anyway I can programmatically do that?  I'm not sure if this would be done on the rails side or the remote-client side.  I'm assuming some jquery on the client side to clear cache, but really looking for some additional perspective on this issue.  I have tried

```
$(#myresultsdiv).empty()
```

with no luck. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to clear the asset pipeline cache, but I disabled nonce usage by using an ajax prefilter:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter('script', function(options) {
options.cache = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would turn off assets pipeline as you are not getting the benefits of it if its being regenerated for every request.

In your environment config:

```
  # Enable asset pipeline
  config.assets.digest = false

  config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: config.assets.digest = false, would not do anything.  i did config.assets.enabled = false instead, and although that does fix the issue, a million more issues arise because of the fact that i have been relying on asset pipeline.  is there a way to do this without turning off asset pipeline?